# Получение данных с сайта и отображение их из БД

Tags: java, android, база-данных

Есть Json файл, через `Retrofit` получаю из него данные и вывожу в `RecyclerView`. Как я выяснил сразу данные обычно не выводят, а сначала записывают в БД и уже из БД выводят в `RecyclerView`.

На данный момент я на таком этапе что в коллекцию загружаю все данные полученные из Json и выводу их в `RecyclerView` в `MainActivity`.

Как мне выстроить логику чтобы при запуске приложения данные брались из БД, а если в БД их нет, то уже брались из Json и записывались в БД и уже потом отображались?

Как я понимаю должно быть так как я выше описал

Вот метод из `MainActivity`, который заполняет коллекцию

```
private void loadData() {

    final ApiService api = ApiClient.getApiService();

    Call<ItemList> call = api.getFairyTailsJSON();


    call.enqueue(new Callback<ItemList>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ItemList> call, Response<ItemList> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                itemList = response.body().getItems();

                adapter = new ItemsAdapter(MainActivity.this, itemList);
                adapter.setItemSendId(MainActivity.this);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, 1));
                recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Не удается найти данные для отображения", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ItemList> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Нет доступа к сайту", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `сразу данные обычно не выводят, а сначала записывают в БД и уже из БД выводят в RecyclerView` -- вовсе необязательно.

Comment: т.е. я могу сразу из json выводить? Это хорошо, сейчас у меня и так, но хостинг глючный где лежат данные и иногда ошибка бывает что не могу получить данные из json. Хотелось бы узнать как реализовать такое. Открывается приложение и смотрит есть ли данные в БД, если есть то брать оттуда, а если нет, то получить из json и записать в БД и потом вывести из БД. Мне собственно непонятно одно как и где указать проверку есть ли данные в бд или нет и чтобы при открытии приложения сразу к json не обращалось, а смотрело в бд

Comment: `т.е. я могу сразу из json выводить?` -- зависит от логики работы приложения. По остальному -- почитайте про БД на Android. Начать можно с sqlite, а уже потом можно почитать, например, про Realm.

Comment: С БД я работал я могу из БД вывести данные в список. Мне нужно пояснение как сделать проверку: при запуске приложения смотреть есть ли в БД данные, если есть вывести их, а если нет получить из json и записать и уже потом вывести в список. проверку эту где необходимо делать?

Comment: Можно сделать запрос к БД: если запрос вернет данные, то они уже есть.

Answer (score 0):

Сделай класс, к примеру `DBHelper`, в котором будет статический метод на проверку заполненности БД, к примеру `public static void checkDB(){...}`. В теле этого метода сделай проверку на наличие данных в БД. Если есть - ничего не делать, если нет - сохраняй данные в БД.
Ну и в `МейнАктивити` просто вызывай `DBHelper.checkDB();`

Comment: примерно понял.. Попробую реализовать

Comment: Если у тебя БД - realm, напиши и я скину кусок кода, с которым работал вчера.

Comment: у меня sqlite).

Comment: @OVERFLOW советую поскорее переходить на realm :) Получилось что-нибудь?

Comment: Пока не делал ничего. Другим занят) А где можно почитать про realm?

Comment: @OVERFLOW [оф. сайт по реалму](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/) документация с наглядными примерами, разобраться проще простого будет :)

Comment: Спасибо большое)